# JNI error while running on Web Sphere Application server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere

I have custom JNI code in my java web application, which i am calling from websphere application server.
I am getting error
E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause spring: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

I have successfully tested library from running test java program from command line.
but while running the same program from websphere application server is giving error.

I tried calling simple library code which just return int value

---

```
Test_JNI.java
```

---

```
public class Test_JNI {
    public static native int  vsttestjni();

    static {
    System.load("fullpath/libvsttestjni.so");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            int ret = vsttestjni();
            System.out.println("Value of ret is :- " + ret);
    }

}
```

---

```
Test_JNI.h
```

---

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Test_JNI */

#ifndef _Included_Test_JNI
#define _Included_Test_JNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 *  * Class:     Test_JNI
 *   * Method:    vsttestjni
 *    * Signature: ()I
 *     */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Test_1JNI_vsttestjni
(JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

---

```
vsttestjni.c
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Test_JNI.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Test_1JNI_vsttestjni
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
    return 112;
}
```